# What does CallInst::Create() return in LLVM?

Tags: c++, llvm, instrumentation

Considering

```
static CallInst *Create(Value *Func,
                      ArrayRef<Value *> Args,
                      const Twine &NameStr = "",
                      Instruction *InsertBefore = 0)
```

this function, I wonder **what the return value of this function** means.

For example, in following code,

```
int foo(int a);
...
Function *foo_ptr = ~~;//say, foo is refered through getOrInsertFunction()
CallInst *ptr = CallInst::Create(foo_ptr, .../* properly set */);
```

the CallInst *ptr is the return value. Abstractly, does ptr mean

1. **an integer value returned by int foo(int);**
2. **or CALL instruction**

I thought number 2 was the answer, but started to get confused looking at some codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both 1 and 2 are "true". It returns the call instruction, whose "value", when we execute the code, will be the return value of the function.

To illustrate, take this little Pascal program:

```
program p;

function f: integer;
begin
   f := 42;
end; { f }

begin
   writeln(f);
end.
```

Which translates to this LLVM-IR:

```
; ModuleID = 'TheModule'
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

%text = type { i32, i8*, i32, i32 }

@input = global %text zeroinitializer, align 8
@output = global %text zeroinitializer, align 8
@UnitIniList = constant [1 x i8*] zeroinitializer

define i32 @P.f() #0 {
entry:
  %f = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 42, i32* %f
  %0 = load i32, i32* %f
  ret i32 %0
}

define void @__PascalMain() #0 {
entry:
  %calltmp = call i32 @P.f()
  call void @__write_int(%text* @output, i32 %calltmp, i32 0)
  call void @__write_nl(%text* @output)
  ret void
}

declare void @__write_int(%text*, i32, i32)

declare void @__write_nl(%text*)

attributes #0 = { "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" }
```

The `call i32 @P.f()` is generated by:

```
inst = builder.CreateCall(calleF, argsV, "calltmp");
```

The contents of `inst` is `%calltmp = call i32 @P.f()` - and that is a `CallInst` 'value'.

and `inst` is returned to the evaluation of the expression for the argument to `writeln`.